# Columns in each table - Year, Month and YearMonth. How can I create a calendar table? In PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have three columns **Year**, **Month** and **YearMonth** on each data source table.

Example,

**Year** - 2020
**Month** - 3
**YearMonth** - 202003

Data type and format of these columns are **Whole number**.

How can I create a common Calendar table which can be linked to the YearMonth column of the each table to make a relationship.
Is there any way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In PowerQuery

- Reference one of your source tables
- Select the Year, Month and YearMonth column
- Remove other columns
- Remove duplicate rows

and here's your calender table. You only need to set up relations between all the YearMonth columns and then you can hide Year, Month and YearMonth in all source tables.